# Typecasting v-for key Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am creating a v-for list based on a range that I am suppling my component:

```
<div class="checkbox" v-for="(value, key) in range">
```

I am suppling my data as a prop like so:

```
"{ 0: '0 stars', 1: '1 star', 2: '2 stars' }"
```

My v-for key will always be set as a string though when I log `typeof`. This is strange since I am passing an object which holds the key as a number and not a string.

I do not want to typecast it constantly when I pass the key along to a method. Is there a way to typecast it easily?

Also what could be causing this to come out as a string instead of a int?

Whenever I console.log my `range` object the keys appear in purple so I am guessing at that point they are still viewed as ints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript objects the **keys** are always strings. It you provide a key that is not a string then its automatically converted to string by javascript. AFAIK it is by design choice .See [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

You can pass index as your third argumemt like this:

```
<div class="checkbox" v-for="(value, key, index) in range">
```

And pass index to your method but as vuejs warns([here)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Array-Change-Detection):

`When iterating over an object, the order is based on the key enumeration order of Object.keys(), which is not guaranteed to be consistent across JavaScript engine implementations.`

Its better to cast like this `myMethod(Number(key))`

Comment: I am already doing the typecasting like your example below. It feels like a bit of a hassle though but I guess I will stick with it. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @Stephan-v since in objects the ordering is not guaranteed as of in arrays you can't rely on the index